# What datasource to use instead of jboss one's?

Tags: oracle, jboss, datasource, connection-pooling

we are removing jboss from spring-based application and considering what a datasource to use instead of jboss's one for oracle. We used such properties (in oracle-ds.xml) as

- min-pool-size
- max-pool-size
- blocking-timeout-millis
- prepared-statement-cache-size
- etc...

didn't find analog params in BasicDataSource, apache connection pool.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at [c3p0](http://sourceforge.net/projects/c3p0/). It should fit your needs. Here are the [configuration details](http://www.mchange.com/projects/c3p0/index.html#configuration).

Comment: Doesn't it support "prepared-statement-cache-size" (The number of prepared statements per connection in an LRU cache)?

Comment: Yes it does. Have a look at http://www.mchange.com/projects/c3p0/index.html#maxStatementsPerConnection

Comment: thanks, so jboss uses its own proprietary implemantion like cp3p0?